# pytube: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span' cipher.py

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl, pytube

Yesterday this works fine, today i'm getting error on my local machine, colab notebook, even on my VPS.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pytube/cipher.py in get_throttling_plan(js)
    409     match = plan_regex.search(raw_code)
    410 
--> 411     transform_plan_raw = find_object_from_startpoint(raw_code, match.span()[1] - 1)
    412 
    413     # Steps are either c[x](c[y]) or c[x](c[y],c[z])
```

from pytube import YouTube
def audio_download(video_url):
audio_file = YouTube(video_url).streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download(filename="audio.mp4")
return 'ok'

Expected to download audio.
I even tried to changes in cipher.py file as said in other solution but not working.

Comment: The error is coming from `match.span()`, which suggests that your `plan_regex.search(raw_code)` is returning `None`. You should probably check your `plan_regex` and `raw_code`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a solution.
cipher.py Line 411

```
transform_plan_raw = find_object_from_startpoint(raw_code, match.span()[1] - 1)
```

to

```
transform_plan_raw = js
```

Comment: Let's provide the link to the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1498#issuecomment-1472963944) to access the most updated state of the question.